# Method of naming shapes in slide master?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I'm working on power point generation programs for my company. I am using the python win32com module which provides full access to the VBA (C#?) COM api.

My current idea is to have the users create generic slide layouts using the slide master. I will then provide an API to create JSON based on python dictionaries for what layouts to apply in what position of presentation and to place what content in what placeholders on each particular slide.

My concern is how to effectively keep track of what placeholders are what on each slide layout. I've been digging around the API and while you can add [names to shapes within a slide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.name) I am failing to see how I can have a user do that through the GUI in the slide master. In the perfect would the user would create a new slide in the slide master and name each shape on the slide. Then to say add something to shape-A the user would reference shape-A as a key in the json.

Is it not possible to name shapes within the slide master? At least through the GUI? Or would I have to create a vba macro for this and add it to the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slides cannot be produced from a slide master. The master is parent to the slide layouts, and layouts are parents to the slides. You can't bypass that architecture.

Shapes acquire default names as they are created. Users can change those names using the Selection Pane (Home>Select>Selection Pane).

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. For example if I am viewing the master slide layout, and go to Home>selection>Selection Pane as you say. If I rename a selection, when i go back to normal view and insert that slide. That selection does not have the same name as the slide master. That's a pretty big bummer. Going to be much harder to keep track of.

Comment: The default shape names have the same text, but a different number on the end. But since users can change the names, using a name might not be reliable. You can check the shape type and position to find if it's the one you want.

Comment: I think the on saving grace is, is that the first time you add the slide to the power point, using the referenced layout. The default shape names will have exact same text and numbers. Now if I insert a slide, using an existing layout, and then change the layout, well then number will be different. So I think I can work with this programmatically.